# Design and Scrum

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum, methodology

I edit my post to be more specific.

I wish to start using Scrum methodology, And would like to know how the Design and Scrum live together ?

In the "Old" world I would build a complete design for my application, saying exactly where each menu should be, and how many buttons it should contain.

By being so precise, I help my dev team to understand where to build reusable components (Such as a menu UI, that will be inherited by sub menus), and give them a "Big Picture" about the app.

**How is this dealt with in Scrum ?**

In Scrum we work by sprints, and it seems like a problem for developers to see a "Big Picture" about the app, because there is no "Big Picture", there is only the next sprint.

Thanks a lot,
Michael.

Comment: It isn't a good idea ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: How is this a C# question?

Comment: This is not a C# question in my Opinion Scrum is the same as `QAD` stands for Quick and Dirty, Code first fix later.. what does this possibly have to do with C# it's a methodology not a framework

Comment: @MichaelEngstler - This is **most certainly** not a C# question.  I am, however, a Certified Scrum Master so shoot me an email at my Hotmail account - listed in my profile - and I can point you to some resources you might find helpful.

Comment: This should be asked on Programmers.SE

Comment: reading of question with not `code formatted` is not nice :)

Comment: -1 for including questions like `Where to put the menu ? Should it be up ? What color should it be ? How should look ?`. From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), `avoid asking subjective questions`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the tags and formatted the text, Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can always give "the big picture" regardless of which methodology you're using. Very briefly, for scrum/agile, you have to remember the goal is to create a working software at the end of every iteration. So, one of your stories would not be create the upper menu, it'll be create an upper menu that has one specific function. Imagine if the whole project is stopped after any iteration, you should have an usable application out of that, no matter how limited it is.

Answer (score 1):

Development methodologies cannot be effectively described in a 200 word SO post.  IF you want to learn about this, read one of the books or take one of the courses.

And, with most development methodologies, either the "high level planning" has already been done by non-developers, or a "plan" has been thrown  over the fence for the developers to pretend to follow while they do what they've always done.

And "Agile" is, ultimately, just that -- developers do what they've always done.  Only with "Agile" you can admit that, rather than pretending to follow some grand (and fictitious) development schedule.

"Scrum" is just a regular technical/planning meeting between developers on a team, with as much of the busy-work as possible removed.  There is no real blueprint or format (though the general rule of keeping it short is good).

There ain't no magic.